# how to set ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I'm still newbie and still learn Java for Android. I have problem when call setIsiarray that always crash.

```
public class sebuaharray {
ArrayList<String> isiarray;
ArrayList<String> lab;

public ArrayList<String> getIsiarray() {
    return isiarray;
}

public void setIsiarray(ArrayList<String> isiarray) {
    this.isiarray = isiarray;
}
}
```

When I call setIsiarray such as this function

```
public void isiarraynya(){
ArrayList<String> arraysementara=new ArrayList<>();
arraysementara.add("Coba nambah");
sebuaharray arraynya;
arraynya.setIsiarray(arraysementara);}
```

Is there any solutions for my problem? Sorry for my bad english :-(

Comment: sebuaharray arraynya = new subuaharray();  should do the trick.

Comment: Which problem ?

Comment: I don't really know. The emulator suddenly force to close. But thanks a lot Jamie its work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create an object of class correctly 
`sebuaharray arraynya = new sebuaharray();`
Next in `sebuaharray` class you must define the array list properly before assigning it

```
ArrayList<String> isiarray = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> lab = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `setIsiarray` method on a variable that is not initialized.

```
sebuaharray arraynya;
```

What you need is to instantiate an object using `new` keyword

```
sebuaharray arraynya = new sebuaharray();
arraynya.setIsiarray(arraysementara);}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, subtle but important.